# CSS hover on the elements before

Tags: css

I want to create star rating by CSS. When user will hover last star, all stars before that star must have another color, e.g.: I will hover minStar3, then minStar1,minStar2 and minStar3 must have different color.

```
<i id="minStar1" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i id="minStar2" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i id="minStar3" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i id="minStar4" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i id="minStar5" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Would you be opposed to using a small jQuery script to achieve this?

Comment: If there is possibility to use only CSS, I want to use only that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create this with `Flexbox` and change order of elements with `flex-direction: row-reverse`. You can also use [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) general sibling selector to select all sibling elements that come after hovered element .

```css
.rating {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
i {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
i:hover ~ i,
i:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <i id="minStar1" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="minStar2" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="minStar3" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="minStar4" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="minStar5" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, but my stars can be clicked, and after that all stars before clicked one are in different color (I give them new class="shine"). When I implemented your solution my colors are inverted even when not hovering.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/093ob2os/
Now that "stars" which should shine are at the right side, not at left side.

Comment: @DonLeo With `flex-direction: row-reverse;` order of elements is reversed so now first element in html is actually last element that you see on screen so if you want to add something on first three elements you actually add that to last three in HTML like this https://jsfiddle.net/093ob2os/1/

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this trick before here on SO, but can't find it back.

To do so, invert the order of the stars.
Wrap them in an element (like a `p` or a `div`)
Give that wrapper `direction: rtl`.

By inverting the direction, the `~` sibling selector can be used.

```css
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  direction: rtl;
}
p>i:hover,
p>i:hover~i {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <i id="minStar5" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">5</i>
  <i id="minStar4" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">4</i>
  <i id="minStar3" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">3</i>
  <i id="minStar2" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">2</i>
  <i id="minStar1" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">1</i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but I found an easiest way to do a star rating only in css.
If the parent element is hovered I fill all the stars. Then I empty all the stars next to the focused star:

```
.container {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container .star{
    pointer-events: auto;
    color:grey;
}

.container:hover .star{
    color:yellow;
}

.container .star:hover ~ .star{
    color:grey;
}
```